# Measuring zmq latency between two python processes in high resolution in windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, zeromq

I want to measure the latency of zeromq between two python processes in high resolution(in a us/ns unit)(windows 10).

Here's my code.

**sub.py**

```
import sys
import zmq
import time

port = "5556"
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    port =  sys.argv[1]
    int(port)

if len(sys.argv) > 2:
    port1 =  sys.argv[2]
    int(port1)

# Socket to talk to server
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)

print('connecting to publisher')
socket.connect ("tcp://localhost:%s" % port)

if len(sys.argv) > 2:
    socket.connect ("tcp://localhost:%s" % port1)
topicfilter = "10001"
socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, topicfilter)

total_value = 0
while True:
    string = socket.recv()
    got_time = time.time() # resolution in windows 10: 15.6ms
    topic, msgdata = string.split()
    dur = got_time - float(msgdata)
    print('it took %.5fms from pub' % (dur*1000))
```

**pub.py**

```
import zmq
import random
import sys
import time

port = "5556"
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    port =  sys.argv[1]
    int(port)

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port)

topic = 10001
while True:
    msgdata = time.time() # resolution in windows 10: 15.6ms
    socket.send_string("%d %.5f" % (topic, msgdata))
    print("topic:%d, msg:%.5f" % (topic, msgdata))
    time.sleep(1)
```

However, since `time.time()` function's resolution in windows 10 is only 15.6ms(windows default timer period), I was unable to measure the latency below 15.6ms with code.

So I thought about using `time.perf_counter()` function, which have microsecond resolution, but it was also useless in measuring time difference of two process since `time.perf_counter()` function's reference point is undefined according to [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter).

Is there any other way to measure the time difference between two python processes in high resolution(microsecond or nanosecond unit)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is: ZeroMQ has a built-in tool for doing this, platform independent and indeed lovely to use.

```
aClk = zmq.Stopwatch()                         // creates a Stopwatch instance
...
..
.
aClk.start();_=aProcessUnderTEST();aClk.stop() // measure an embedded latency
2169L                                          // <-------------------latency[us]
```

**`.stop()`** method returns a long number ( `1234L` ), representing a duration **with a [us] resolution.**

**Hints:** avoid any printing and memory-allocation operations when going down into testing performance details ( always **pre-allocate**, always rather assign a function's returning value, than to get interpreter's result-value repr/printing overheads included into the measurement-embedded section-of-code == **avoid `repr()` overheads by assignment to `_`** ( special symbol ( variable ) without any allocation overhead ) ).

---

Still, there are points to solve ( or to be aware of ):

**- on distributed hosts,** ( non-local process-starts/ends ) you need to find and synchronise a common reference-clock to compute meaningful differences, or one has to re-arrange the test to form a loop in message/signal delivery there-and-back to measure on the same refClk-side. For additional aspects of high-res clocks ( having sub-`1E-6` resolutions ), monotonicity ( immune to NTP-adjustments ), kindly check **`time.process_time()`**, **`time.perf_counters()`** and one may use more complex scenarios to measure differentially, as one message triggers beginning of test-measurement and the second arrival triggers end of the test-measurement, carrying the initiator-side inter-message duration ( processing, intended delay et al ) overhead ( in `[us]` ) as a payload ( to substitute from the result on the receiver side ). Anyway, be careful on below mentioned systematic uncertainties when dealing sub-`[us]`-events.

**- expect O/S interventions** on various ZeroMQ transport-classes. The **`tcp://`** transport-class, for instance, is a subject of Windows buffering and there have been published heavily unpredictable deferred wireline transmits on Windows TCP/IP-stack ( google 'em, countermeasures exist, google 'em too ).

**- expect O/S scheduler** influences on how **`aProcessUnderTEST`** is being executed amongst all other system + user processing and prioritised resources handling.